# Fire custom method when user impersonation begins in Kentico 9

Tags: kentico

We are on Kentico 9. When a user logs into our website, a cookie is set for the user. However, when I log in to the admin site, then impersonate a user, the cookie still holds information pertaining to my user (not the impersonated user). I'd like the cookie to be replaced with one that holds the information of the impersonated user. Therefore, I need a method to fire when impersonation begins. Does Kentico provide a way to hook into the impersonation process to fire a custom method?

I've found that method `AuthenticationHelper.ImpersonateUser` is called when you impersonate a user, but I don't see a way to do what I want.

The only places I see this method called are in `~\CMSAdminControls\UI\UserMenu.ascx.cs` and `~\CMSModules\Membership\Pages\Users\User_Edit_General.aspx.cs`, but I'm not sure I want to go modifying those code files.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use [global events](https://docs.kentico.com/k9/custom-development/handling-global-events/reference-global-system-events) specially [Application events](https://docs.kentico.com/k9/custom-development/handling-global-events/reference-global-system-events#Reference-Globalsystemevents-Applicationevents). Here is the [example how to attach to global event](https://docs.kentico.com/k9/custom-development/handling-global-events). Try to hook up to a global event like Authenticate and see if it works for you.

Answer (score 0):

If the public, authenticated, non-content editor users are not specifically using the Impersonate feature of Kentico then you're performing your testing incorrectly by simply impersonating a user.  You should be performing your testing in an in-private window.  Using a Global Event Handler to overwrite the CMS cookie will cause problems when you navigating around and when you cancel the impersonation.

Comment: I don't want to overwrite the CMS cookie, but rather a different custom cookie that's specific to our website. I don't quite understand what you mean by "testing in an in-private window". Do you mean an IE "InPrivate" window?

Comment: Is the "Impersonate User" part of your public user settings?  If not, why not just force this custom cookie on authentication?  The authentication event is fired when you impersonate a user as well so should be able to capture this event in the authentication event and still write your cookie.

Comment: @BrendanKehren That sounds reasonable. I'll look into when I get back to this. Thanks.